# How to use NSTimer to update a label?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a label that I want to update the text of it with multiple displays over a period of time when a touch is recoded. I can use performSelector but it seems bulky...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self changeTextForLabel:@"A text (1)"]; // When touch begins the display is changed
[self performSelector:@selector(changeTextForLabel:) withObject:@"Another text (2)" afterDelay:1];               // After 1 second update to this
[self performSelector:@selector(changeTextForLabel:) withObject:@"And another text (3)" afterDelay:2];           // after 2 seconds update to this
[self performSelector:@selector(changeTextForLabel:) withObject:@"And even another text (4)" afterDelay:3];      // After 3 seconds update to this
[self performSelector:@selector(changeTextForLabel:) withObject:@"And yes even another text (5)" afterDelay:3]; }
```

I heard people talk about using timers to execute a method every x seconds, but i dont understand how to use it for my situation. What i have is..

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
[self changeTextForLabel:@"A text (1)"];
[self changeTextForLabel:@"Another text (2)"];
[self changeTextForLabel:@"And another text (3)"];
[self changeTextForLabel:@"And even another text (4)"];
[self changeTextForLabel:@"And yes even another text (5)"];
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }
```

But this only displays the very last message.. but i want it to display one after another after 1 second.
I tried to use pause() or sleep() in between every message but it only delays the time before the the label is updated and it gets updated with the last message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because you're updating each label without waiting one second. Try something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray* titles;

...

- (NSArray*) titles {
    if(!_titles)
        _titles= @[@"A text (1)", @"Another text (2)", @"And another text (3)", @"And even another text (4)", @"And yes even another text (5)"];
    return _titles;
}

- (void)updateLabel:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(self.titles.count)
    {
        [self changeTextForLabel: self.titles[0] ];
        // Alternatively use a NSMutableArray
        self.titles= [self.titles subarrayWithRange: NSMakeRange(1,self.titles.count-1) ];
    }
    else { // Invalidate the timer
    }
}
```

If you want to re-initialize the array to display all the titles again, it's enough that you set `titles` to `nil`, so that the next time you'll call the getter, the array will be initialized again:

```
self.titles= nil;  // Now _titles is nil
self.titles; // Not it's the full array with all the 5 objects
```

**Alternative**

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    static unsigned int count=0;
    [self changeTextForLabel: self.titles[count++ % self.titles.count] ];
    if(count==5) {
        // Invalidate the timer
    }
}
```

PS: With this last code you don't need to reset the array. When `count` overflows it will restart to zero, so it's stable and safe.

Comment: In the - (NSArray)titles method if I use self.titles it crashes. Do you know why?
Plus when the display finishes, how can i get it to go through the display once again when i click?

Comment: Inside - (NSArray*) titles if you use self.titles you crash because self.titles calls - (NSArray*) titles ; The dot notation is just a shortcut to call the getter/setter. So you crash because you call recursively the getter, and the recursion never ends. Use _titles instead of self.titles .

Comment: To display again the 5 titles, you need to reset the titles array. You do this simply by setting titles to nil, so that when you call self.titles again, the array will be re-initialized. I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: In the edit I also added an alternative (and cleaner) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add an NSTimer property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

A function to start the timer:

```
-(void) startTimer
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(timerTick:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.timer fire];
}
```

Timer tick event to get current time:

```
//Event called every time the NSTimer ticks.
- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{

    Date *currentTime = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    NSString *timeNow = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:value];;

    [self updateDisplay:timeNow];
}
```

Needs to update display on main thread:

```
-(void)updateDisplay:(NSString *)str
{
    //NSLog(@"update display: %@", str);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setLabelText:)
                           withObject:str
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Setting the label text :)

```
-(void) setLabelText:(NSString *)labelText
{
    [self.label setText:labelText];
}
```

Comment: scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval already adds the timer to the run loop, you don't need to add it again.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Thanks, Does it also fires it ?

Comment: Yes, it also fires it.