# Where do I put my loop?

Tags: objective-c

I really need some help on where to put this loop:

```
int timer = 10;
while (timer >= 0) {
[secondsLeft setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", timer]];
NSLog(@"%d", timer);
timer--;
sleep(1);
}
```

Anyways, wherever I put this loop I get some sort of error except for under the IBAction where it works perfectly except it delays the button press by 10 seconds :P

Here's my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize answer;
@synthesize secondsLeft;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

}

- (IBAction)answerButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *str = answer.text;        // Takes user input from answer.text
    int answerOne = [str intValue];     // converts answer into an integer

    if(answerOne == 30) {
        self.secondsLeftToAnswer.text = @"Correct!";
    } else {
            self.secondsLeftToAnswer.text = @"You Suck at Math!";
        }
    }

@end
```

Anyways can someone please tell me how I can implement this loop into my code so that the loop displays its output to a UILabel (secondsLeft is the UILabel, loop is supposed to display a countdown from 10 to 0 in the UILabel) ?

EDIT: How would I go about implementing a NSTimer to do what I want (countdown from 10)? I tried to set one up but they are so confusing. Thanks for the help so far Jasarien!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "nowhere". Cocoa is an event-driven system and such loops stop the main thread from processing events and you won't see the text of the label change and user-interaction will be disabled.  See the [Main Event Loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html) documentation for details.

Instead use an `NSTimer` ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081265/how-to-use-nstimer-to-update-a-label)), which works with the runloop to allow periodic method invocation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a loot at NSTimer's!

Answer (score 0):

In order to show countdown you need to update the label after specific time.

Below is the code depicting the functionality you want.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

count = 10;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(handleTimer)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: YES];
}


-(void)handleTimer{

if (count >= 0) {
    [lblTimer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)count]];
    count--;

}else{
    [timer invalidate];

}

}
```

Hope this will help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately this code gives me several "Use of undeclared identifier 'count' and 'timer'. Do I need to define those anywhere before this code?

Comment: Ya definitely you need to define them globally.

Comment: @user3860138 if you got help than try to vote on the answers which helped you. This way people are motivated